# How to prevent string from printing repeatedly in while loop?

Tags: java, string, while-loop, println

I'm currently working on some exercises given to me by my teacher. These are for the holidays so I won't be able to ask for help there.

I have this piece of code which creates a multiplication table from an integer defined by the user, ranging from a minimum and maximum also defined by the user.

Before setting any of my variables to the next integer in my Scanner, I do a check to see if the Scanner actually has an integer. This works fine but I don't want it to print out the error message a billion times.

Any tips/tricks or other special ways of getting around this?

```
public class MultiplicationTable
{
    private int intervalMin;
    private int intervalMax;
    private int multiplier;
    private int result;
    private Scanner sc;

    public MultiplicationTable()
    {
        multiplier = 0;
        intervalMin = 0;

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (multiplier == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the integer you wish to show the table for");
            if (sc.hasNextInt())
            {
                multiplier = sc.nextInt();

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Input is not an integer\n");
            }
        }

        while (intervalMin == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the integer defining the start of the table");
            if (sc.hasNextInt())
            {
                intervalMin = sc.nextInt();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Input is 0 or not an integer\n");
            }

        }

        while (intervalMax == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the integer defining the end of the table");
            if (sc.hasNextInt())
            {
                int i = sc.nextInt();
                if (i > intervalMin)
                {
                    intervalMax = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("\nEnd integer must be greater than start integer");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Input is 0 or not an integer");
            }

        }

        System.out.println("\nTable for integer " + multiplier + " from " + intervalMin + " to " + intervalMax + "\n");
        for (int i = intervalMin; i <= intervalMax; i++)
        {
            result = i * multiplier;
            System.out.println(i + " * " + multiplier + " = " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't consume what user entered into the scanner buffer, that's why sc.hasNextInt() keeps getting executed without waiting for the next user input.
The solution is to add sc.nextLine() after the if condition.
For example:

```
boolean gotInteger = false;
    while (!gotInteger) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the integer you wish to show the table for");
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            multiplier = sc.nextInt();
            gotInteger = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input is not an integer\n");
        }
        sc.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: sc.nextLine will consume the last user input and when call sc.hasNextInt again, it will wait for another user input.

Comment: It for sure does work. Thanks a lot! However, I can't say I fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try this, just wrap all your code inside try catch:

```
try {
    while (intervalMax == 0) {
        System . out . println("\nPlease enter the integer defining the end of the table");
        if (sc . hasNextInt()) {

            int i = sc . nextInt();

            if (i > intervalMin) {
                intervalMax = i;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("\nEnd integer must be greater than start integer");
            }
         }

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System . out . println(e . getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that does put an end to the printing. But the point is that it has to return to the top of the while-loop until it actually gets an integer.